# What interface software system is used in superuser?

Tags: support, interface, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Can't find it anywhere.

It looks very alike www.vark.com/community which is the uservoice I've confused it with at first, and even more to unity3d answers, which might pretty much be the same.

Comment: phpBB - That's the core of Super User.

Comment: so it isn't http://doctype.com ?

Comment: interface software?  it's firefox, isn't it?

Comment: Also, if interested in what are these sites made with: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incase no one bothered to tell you, StackOverflow, SuperUser and Serverfault are the original implementations of this style of user interface. Doctype came afterwards, and since it is related to what we do, we linked to them.

Those 3 sites actually run on the same software StackExchange runs on, which makes sense because StackExchange was the product of StackOverflow's success. They took the user interface  and made it available to others for a charge.

However, we are the originals. And the source-code is not open source and/or buy-able (for under a couple million)

---

I'd like to put this under the **[generation-gap]** tag. It seems like everyone just assumes that a site is built on another site's framework or an open source project. While StackOverflow does have some OpenSource components, it was pretty much developed ground up.

Comment: Thanks. That answers it. Does it have a name? How could I have found about this on my own?

Comment: Ummm .. by searching in the top right search bar for "What was StackOverflow built with"

Comment: It doesn't really have a name. You can get something similar by searching for StackExchange (they sell sites like this for a cost), but the interface itself is just the site.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I've finally found a good FAQ, interestingly using Wiki, with your hint. Eventually I'll read it more deeply.