# What backend / CMS Scipting is this site running?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What interface software system is used in superuser?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1015/what-interface-software-system-is-used-in-superuser)

What does this site run on? I'm interested in something similar for a different purpose.

Thanks

Comment: Questions about Super User should be directed at our [Meta site](http://meta.superuser.com) or [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - where you will find that this question has already been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

All details are revealed on Meta Stackoverflow here: [What is StackOverflow Built With](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)